# Convention for calculating class attribute in Java constructor

Tags: java, constructor

What's the convention for calculating a class attribute in Java?

For example, doing the calculation directly in the constructor:

```
public class Person {
    public Person(int birthyear){
        this.birthyear = birthyear;
        this.age = 2020 - birthyear;
    }    
}
```

compared to calling a method that does the calculation:

```
public class Person {
    public Person(int birthyear){
        this.birthyear = birthyear;
        this.age = calculateAge(birthyear);
    }    
}
```

Where the calculation is complex (not like here), I'm inclined to go with the second example, but would like to follow conventions, where possible.

This may be a duplicate, in which case please point me in the right direction (couldn't find it from my searching).

Comment: For simple complex cases, a private method can be called. For complex complex cases, there are even more options (builders, factory methods and so on).

Comment: Maybe [initializer blocks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-26-the-initializer-block-in-java/) are interesting to you, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not really a convention. It rather depends on the complexity or readability of the calculations.
For a simple one like `2020 - birthyear` I would consider it perfectly fine if it were put right there in the constructor.

With more complex cases, I would rather defer it to a method. **But remember: make sure you make it private**, otherwise a subclass can get access to a not fully constructed object.